# Подскажите куда и как добавить .js

Tags: javascript, jsfiddle

Хочется на форуме указать ссылку на таймер, значит нужно куда-то добавить скрипт, попытался добавить на jsfiddle.net но не получилось...
Подскажите куда и как я могу добавить такой код:

```
<script src="http://megatimer.ru/s/81fbbbb5b43bc4ceb5900ab17a7ff6d2.js"></script>
```

Comment: о каком форуме речь? Что значит _на форуме указать ссылку на таймер_? Откуда взялся этот тег скрипт?

Comment: > Что значит на форуме указать ссылку на таймер?
Хочу на форуме узазать ссылку, когда человек переходит по ней, увидит таймер, ссылка приблизительно такого вида jsfiddle.net/afabbro/vrVAP

> Откуда взялся этот тег скрипт?
Я добавил, тег скрипт, но его тут же удалили.

Comment: Куда ты его добавил? Почему ты думаешь, что его удалили?

Comment: > Почему ты думаешь, что его удалили?Ко мне пришло сообщение о редактировании... обновился, странно вроде всё на месте...

Comment: > Откуда взялся этот тег скрипт? С сайта, где конфигурируется таймер megatimer.ru

Comment: Еще раз: о каком форуме идет речь? и куда конкретно ты вставил этот скрипт?

Comment: > Еще раз: о каком форуме идет речь? | Я не понимаю вопроса... я попросил на форуме помощи в создании логотипа, время идёт, нет смысла просто ждать, решил добавить таймер на форум, мол через неделю тема будет закрыта... | 

> и куда конкретно ты вставил этот скрипт? | Я пытался добавить скрипт с сайта megatimer.ru на сайт jsfiddle.net

Comment: На каком форуме??? У этого форума есть название? Если ли у него адрес?

Comment: Вы не являетесь владельцем форума и у вас нет доступа к исходному коду, верно?

Comment: Я не владелец, мне просто нужен логотип, поэтому обратился за помощью на два форума maultalk.com и webmasters.ru

Comment: > Вы не являетесь владельцем форума и у вас нет доступа к исходному коду, верно? | У вас получается запустить скрипт с сайта megatimer.ru на сайте jsfiddle.net?

Answer (score -4):

Всё, сделал, зашёл на сайт jsbin.com , в body добавил скрипт с сайта megatimer.ru , потом File - Export as gist - Open in new tab - output.jsbin.com/rizebojahe

Comment: Чтобы дополнить свой вопрос, просим вас воспользоваться опцией редактирования. Кнопку «Опубликовать ответ» следует использовать только для исчерпывающих ответов на вопросы. - [Из очереди проверок](/review/low-quality-posts/213474)

Comment: @Air, вообще-то это ответ.

Comment: @RostyslavKuzmovych, вообще-то это ответ.